# mvc posting dropdownlist selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

good evening,

I have a bit of trouble passing the selected value to the controller from my View. I don't understand how i need to pass the value, i have been searching for information with no avail. here is my code

Controller [GET]

```
            [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddProduct()
    {
      ideaworktelekrik.Models.ProductModel newProduct = new Models.ProductModel();
      newProduct.Categories = new SelectList( (from a in dbContext.Categories select new SelectListItem { Text = a.Category1, Value = a.ID.ToString()  }),"Value","Text");

        return View(newProduct);
    }
```

View:

```
            <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.c_ID, Model.Categories)
    </div>
```

Model:

```
            public string Name {get;set;}
    public int c_ID { get; set; }
    public Guid _ID {get;set;} 
    public string imageurl {get;set;}
    public SelectList Categories {get;set;}
    public string CategorySelected { get; set; }
```

If it's possible, please let me know the logic behind the process as the main target for this question is to learn how the values are passed (amogst getting it to work).

Just so that you know what this project is about, this is an Add product page, where the user has a couple of text boxes to enter product information and at the end selecting the category(dropdown) for the product, Hence the other variables in the model.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the select list you need to tell it the selected value, see below:

```
  newProduct.Categories = new SelectList( items: (from a in dbContext.Categories select new SelectListItem { Text = a.Category1, Value = a.ID.ToString() })
                                                selectedValue: newProduct.c_ID)
                                                , "Value", "Text");
```

This is for setting it when doing the get if you are having a problem with the post, can you put up your form and controller post method, ( I am assuming it would be populating the c_ID on the model at the time of posting ).

Comment: i added this

                    newProduct.Categories = new SelectList((from a in dbContext.Categories select new SelectListItem { Text = a.Category1, Value = a.ID.ToString() }), "Value", "Text",selectedValue:newProduct.c_ID);

and it's still returning null when posting

Answer (score 0):

> I have a bit of trouble passing the selected value to the controller
>   from my View.

Without seeing your model properties, the simple version of code would be:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.c_ID, Model.Categories)
  </div>

  // any other form fields here

  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
}
```

And your controller post-action would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProduct(ProductModel model)
{
    // process your model data here
}
```

Comment: my current system is set exactly as you suggested, still returns null.

Comment: @Eric Matson apologies, but there is a missing bracket or something in your code,

Comment: 1) by "returns null", do you mean the data being sent from the form is null?

2) Are you sure that your dropdown list has numbers for values, and not just the text of the category?

3) What happens if you change the helper to be loosely typed (@DropDownList("ID", Model.Categories) ?

Comment: hey, i just found out my problem, i was not returning the model in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, basically i had the wrong understanding of how MVC works.

i was populating the selectList in the Get actionMethod and not in the Post actionMethod, therefore when the post was being executed it was empty parameters to the dropdownlist.

I also had some wrong logic in my selectList creation (thanks @Eric) and also in my view (Thanks @Eckert)

Thanks guys!